# Trying to allign text on one line

Tags: html

I have some HTML that seems to allign my text, but it uses the height at which the facebook and twitter icons are not the line text. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The site is [NPN360](http://www.npn360.com) and the code I am working with is at the bottom of the page.

```
 div class="footer">
        &copy; 2014 NPN360 &#149; All rights reserved &#149; 1400 South Wolf Road, Suite #102 &#149; Wheeling, IL 60090 &#149; 847-215-7300 
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Northern-Printing-Network/179242349742" target="_blank"><img src="/images/facebook_16.png" /></a> 
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/130676?trk=tyah" target="_blank"><img src="/images/linkedin_16.png" /></a> 
<span style="float:right;"><td><font size="1"><a href="http://restaurantinc.com/privacypolicy" target="_blank"> Privacy Policy</a>.</span>
</p>
    </div> <!-- footer -->
```

Comment: Where does the `td` come from?

Comment: Disregard that, I deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated after comments**

```
<div class="footer">
<style>
.footer img {
padding-left: 5px;
vertical-align: sub;
}
label#lbl { vertical-align: 5px; }
</style>
<label id="lbl"> &copy; 2014 NPN360 &#149; All rights reserved &#149; 1400 South Wolf Road, Suite #102 &#149; Wheeling, IL 60090 &#149; 847-215-7300 </label>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Northern-Printing-Network/179242349742" 

target="_blank"><img src="/images/facebook_16.png" /></a> 
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/130676?trk=tyah" target="_blank"><img src="/images/linkedin_16.png" /></a> 
<span style="float:right;"><font size="1"><a href="http://restaurantinc.com/privacypolicy" target="_blank"> Privacy Policy</a>.</span>
    </p>
  </div> <!-- footer -->
```

Comment: But then how do I align the privacy policy to match the line text?

Comment: Where do you want `privacy policy` to be exactly placed at?

Comment: I want it on the same line all the way to the right, but at the same height as the text. Right now its using the height of the images of facebook and twitter.

Comment: Write your text in a label like this `<label id="lbl">© 2014 NPN360 • All rights reserved • 1400 South Wolf Road, Suite #102 • Wheeling, IL 60090 • 847-215-7300 </label>` and then give this label a height using this CSS `label#lbl {
vertical-align: 5px;
}`

Comment: `5px` is just for example. Try to give height in `px` and use which ever suits your layout.

Comment: You just need the to replace the line in your HTML with the one I posted in comment above. and Copy paste `label#lbl` CSS in your CSS.

Comment: remove `vertical-align` from `.footer img` and they will be placed just as they were before editing. and now change the `vertical-align` of `label` to adjust it wherever you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from many HTML errors, the simplest way to fix alignment is to drop the float on the footer element and put text-align instead:

```
.footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And to fix the height of the images, start with:

```
.footer img {
    vertical-align: middle; // try also baseline, text-bottom, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Not sure if I am doing this correctly.

```
<div class="footer">
<style>
.footer img {
padding-left: 5px;
vertical-align: sub;
}
label#lbl { vertical-align: 5px; }
</style>
<label id="lbl">        &copy; 2014 NPN360 &#149; All rights reserved &#149; 1400 South Wolf Road, Suite #102 &#149; Wheeling, IL 60090 &#149; 847-215-7300 </label>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Northern-Printing-Network/179242349742" target="_blank"><img src="/images/facebook_16.png" /></a> 
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/130676?trk=tyah" target="_blank"><img src="/images/linkedin_16.png" /></a> 
<label id="lbl"><span style="float:right;"><font size="1"><a href="http://restaurantinc.com/privacypolicy" target="_blank"> Privacy Policy</a>.</span></label>
</p>
    </div> <!-- footer -->
```

Comment: You're using same `id` for two elements. Try it only with `text` and not with `privacy policy`

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. Just copy paste it.